# How to receive multiple messages in python-telegram-bot?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am sending multiple images at a time to a bot in telegram. I am trying to create a `conversational chatbot` using python-telegram bot.

here is my code:

```
def main():
updater = Updater("1141074258:Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxg", use_context=True)

dp = updater.dispatcher
conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points = [CommandHandler('start',start)],

    states = {
    CHOSEN_OPTION: [MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^(Option2|Option3|Option4)$'),choose_option)],
    PRODUCTS: [MessageHandler(Filters.text | Filters.photo,products)],
    Option2: [MessageHandler(Filters.text,option2)],
    Option3: [MessageHandler(Filters.text,option3)],
    Option4: [CommandHandler('create', create_order)]
    },
    fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)]
)
dp.add_handler(conv_handler)
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()



@run_async
def products(update,context):
    logger.info("update is %s",update)
    input_message = update.message.text
    if input_message:
        data['products'] = input_message
        logger.info("product  text is:%s",input_message)
    elif update.message.photo:
        photo_list = []
        bot = context.bot
        length = len(update.message.photo)
        for photo in range(0,length):
            ident = update.message.photo[photo].file_id
            getFile = context.bot.get_file(ident)
            photo_list.append(getFile['file_path'])
        data['products_image'] = photo_list
    update.message.reply_text("Please type name.",)
    return Option3
```

If i am send 2 images same time, i am getting one image with a different size (3 times), How can I receive the actual two messages?

Comment: could you share your products function ?

Comment: ohhh there is problem in your products function. after getting first photo you return Option3 that await for a text and after that goes to option3 function. and don't accept photo

Comment: while you have photo in your update return PRODUCTS

Comment: @mujad yes, that's exactly the problem. How can i solve this? How can i know the end of the message to return option3?

Comment: what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I am sending list of products or image of products, some time i will send one image or more than one image, it works fine if i send 1 image only. If i send more than one image, only can process one image. Instead of that, i need to collect all images and process it, after that return Option3.

Comment: for every message telegram send and update to your bot you can collect data while update.message.photo is not  and stay in your PRODUCTS state when collect all photos and update.message.photo is None you can return to every state you want

Answer (score 0):

if update contains photo return PRODUCTS for getting other photos else
get text and return to every state you want

```py
@run_async
def products(update,context):
    logger.info("update is %s",update)
    if update.message.photo:
        # to what you want with your photos
        
        return PRODUCTS
    
    if update.message.text:
        # getting product text 
        
        return Option3
```